# Terminal Error While Installing PyMySQL

Tags: terminal, python, raspberry-pi, mysql, raspbian

I'm working on a project with the Raspberry Pi that involves connecting it to a MySQL database. After doing some research, I have found PyMySQL to be what I need to install through the terminal. I've tried to download it with

```
pip install PyMySQL
```

but I am just getting the following error:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
status = self.run(options, args)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 295, in run
requirement_set.install(install_options, global_options, root=options.root_path)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1436, in install
requirement.install(install_options, global_options, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 672, in install
self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 902, in move_wheel_files
pycompile=self.pycompile,
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 214, in move_wheel_files
clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 204, in clobber
os.makedirs(destdir)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyMySQL-0.8.0.dist-info'

Storing debug log for failure in /home/pi/.pip/pip.log
```

Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to install PyMySql to your system without sufficient permissions. You can see the install script fail when it tries to create a new directory:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyMySQL-0.8.0.dist-info'
```

**Do not resolve this by using `sudo`.** Installing Python packages via `sudo pip` can cause serious problems with your system.

The solution is to install any Python packages you want to use for this project into a [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/).

A good way to make use of virtualenv is through [virtualenvwrapper](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), which makes using virtualenv quick and easy.